# htaccess in development folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a working site and dev site.The htaccess code in dev site starts with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.co.uk/dev2$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Where dev2 is the folder name under root.But whenever I click a link from dev2 site it is redirecting to the live site. I think the problem is in the second line?

Comment: Looks like you should first decide if you want ot keep www or not and then enforce it.

Comment: I would like to keep www but I am not sure how to do enforcing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.co.uk/dev2/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

or the more verbose:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.co.uk/dev2/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mate.But now the url looks like http://www.abc.co.uk/dev2index.php.....Any idea please.